# How to solve compile error "taking address of temporary array" in android ndk 10 e but not in Xcode?

Tags: android, c++, xcode, android-ndk

I created some function which accepts a pair array like that:

```
void test(std::pair<std::string,bool> v[],int size){
    //I need to use lambda so copy content to local variable first
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,bool> > v_cp(v,v+size);
    //some lambda
}
```

and then call it:

```
test((std::pair<std::string,bool>[]){std::make_pair("idle",true)},1);
```

the code can compile in Xcode but not compile in android ndk:

```
error: taking address of temporary array
 test((std::pair<std::string,bool>[]){std::make_pair("idle",true)},1);
                                                                    ^
```

is there compile flag that can solve the problem without changing the code? or is there other syntax to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a C style open array, and you can initialize like this:

```
std::pair<std::string, bool> arr[] = { std::make_pair("idle", true) };
test(arr, 1);
```

I guess you must have your reason to has a C style open array in your function parameter, or otherwise vector will be better in passing arbitrary number of array elements.